# Mysql alter statement

Tags: mysql, alter

this is my alter statement trying to connect two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts 
  CHANGE `profession` `profession_id`  INT NOT NULL, 
  ADD CONSTRAINT professions_profession_id_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (profession_id) REFERENCES professions (profession_id)
```

and I have the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`contacts`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-1ca_73'>, CONSTRAINT `professions_profession_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`profession_id`) REFERENCES `professions` (`profession_id`))
```

can anyone guide me on what this is? I am actually learning how to write sql myself since I have used tools all this while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key constraint is failing.

The foreign key you are trying to create enforces every profession_id in my_contacts to be present in your professions table. Right now, this is not the case. You should lookup all records in my_contacts where the profession_id is not present in professions and fix those first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relationship conflict. An easier to solve this is

- Remove the relationship between the fields
- Alter the tables
- While adding the relationship again, fix the errors you receive.